# ASP check request method

Tags: asp-classic

How do i check if my form has been submitted in classic ASP?

Comment: perhaps, check the extension of the referrer

Comment: this is an unclear question. what do you want to know ? if the form left the client on its way to the server when you pressed submit ? was the data received as a form (post) and not query string data (get) ? was the data processed by the server with no errors ? too many options here.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First, you can check, if `Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD")= "POST"`. That is, assuming, you use POST method to submit the form, the initial load will have GET method, the subsequent submits will be POST.

You can also add a hidden field in your form, if that variable is set in POST data (`Request.Form` object), you will know it is a postback, otherwise it is the first load.

Comment: Checking request method and referrer will give you something like PostBack :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Function IsPostBack()
  IsPostBack = false    
  If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") <> "POST" Then
    Exit Function       
  End If
  Dim referer: referer = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")
  Dim current: current = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ORIGIN") & Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")
  Dim i: i = InStr(1, referer, "?", 1)
  If i > 1 Then
    referer  = Left(referer, i - 1)
  End If
  IsPostBack = LCase(current) = LCase(referer)
End Function
```