# Alert message on button click event

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I have a button and textbox on my page aspx and on button click event I am displaying alert message.

Now when I run website and click on button it display message but after that when I press <kbd>F5</kbd> (Refresh) it again display message. So my question how to remove message when I click <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Below is my code for button click:

```
  protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      DisplayMessage("There is no data to Export.", this);
        
  }
```

and

```
public void DisplayMessage(String strMessage, Control name)
{
    string script = "<script language='javascript'>alert('" + strMessage + "');</script>";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(name, name.GetType(), "JSCR", script, false);
}
```

Comment: on page load assign empty value to that message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your script as follows

```
string script = "alert('hello');window.location.href='Default.aspx'";
```

where i assumed `Default.aspx` is your page

Answer (score 0):

You are instigating a client side event from server side which usually does not make sense.

The behaviour you are noticing is correct, when you clicked that button a request is posted to the server which calls your button click handler which then registers the client side script when the response is returned.  When you press F5 to refresh your browsers is posting that exact same request again to the server, so the button handler is fired again.

I advise you read a little about how [Post And Gets](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)
 work as well as how [postbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251157/what-is-a-postback) work in ASP.

Comment: so that's how it works, In struts I have to take measures to retain the value after page refresh!

Comment: ASP does have Viewstate which if enabled will retain values in forms between postbacks automatically.

Comment: and by default it is always on ?

Comment: Viewstate should be on by default yes.