# Keep page contents while post back

Tags: c#, asp.net

When ever i do postback the page get blanked, i have seen some pages, where page is not being blank while post back

can some give me idea how it can be done

Thank You

Comment: Can you please describe what content you are referring to?

Comment: Can you post your code.? may be you are writing your code outside(!IspostBack) property of the page.

Comment: this is simple page,like you have lable and a button, when u click on button it gets post back then lable reload, i want to label not disappear while post back

Comment: Have you written any !ispostback property of the page in pageload method..??

Comment: See the answers below. This is what I meant.

Comment: Is your viewstate enabled for that page?

Answer (score 2):

```
   private void Page_Load()
    {
       if (IsPostBack)
        {
             // It is a postback
         } 
     else  
        {
              // It is not a postback
         }

         }
```

refer this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Did you bind data on [post back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251157/what-is-a-postback)?
example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       textBox1.Text = "";
    }
```

try adding if(!IsPostBack)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if(!IsPostBack)
     {
        textBox1.Text = "";
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using update panels. This way you  only have to post back the areas that require post back. You will not feel the flicker.