# Saving Data to the Database from Dynamically created asp.net textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, dynamic-controls

First off, I've seen a ton of posts for this same question but what I don't understand is when somebody gives an answer about "recreating the controls to page init" or ... I have the code to dynamically CREATE the text boxes but I'm not sure what else I need to add. I don't completely understand the page life cycle of asp.net web apps. I've googled this and I dont know if I'm incompetent or if all of the answers given are for people with more understanding than me.

PLEASE provide an example of what you explain.

Basically The user enteres a # into the textbox for how many "favorite books" they want to save into the database, he/she clicks the generate button.

that # of rows will populate with two textboxes, one for title and one for author. Then I would have a button they click that would save the textbox values into the database.

I know it's a simple exercise but I'm new to asp.net and it's just an exercise I came up by myself that I'm trying to learn. I'm open to new design for this but the one thing I prefer not to do is create the textboxes statically. Thanks! <3

this is the asp.net code I have

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    How many favorite books do you have ?
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnBookQty" runat="server" Text="GenerateBooks" OnClick="btnBookQty_Click" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlBooks" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
</div>
</form>
```

and my c# code is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class databasetest_panels_favBookWebsite : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void btnBookQty_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);



    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();
        tb.Text = "Book  " + i.ToString() + " Title";
        tb2.Text = "Book  " + i.ToString() + " Author";
        tb.ID = "TextBoxTitle" + i.ToString();
        tb2.ID = "TextBoxAuthor" + i.ToString();
        pnlBooks.Controls.Add(tb);
        pnlBooks.Controls.Add(tb2);
        pnlBooks.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

    } 
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When somebody says that "You need to keep track of the controls you create or recreate them" it means that you need to store them between [postbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251157/what-is-a-postback).

In ASP.NET persistance can means Session variables, ViewStates and other means
See this link [**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx)

Create a list of the textboxes that you created and store it on a Session

```
private void CreateOrLoadTextBoxes(int numTextBoxes)
{
    List<TextBox> lstControls ;
    
    //if its the first time the controls need to be created
    if(Session["lstTitleControls"] == null)
    {
        lstTbTitles = new List<TextBox>(numTextBoxes) ;
        lstTbAuthors = new List<TextBox>(numTextBoxes) ;

        //create the controls for Book Titles
        for (int i = 1; i <= numTextBoxes; i++)
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Text = "Book  " + i.ToString() + " Title";
            tb.ID = "TextBoxTitle" + i.ToString();
            lstTbTitles.Add(tb) ;
        } 

        //Create the controls for Author
        for (int i = 1; i <= numTextBoxes; i++)
        {
            TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();
            tb2.Text = "Book  " + i.ToString() + " Author";
            tb2.ID = "TextBoxAuthor" + i.ToString();
            lstTbAuthors.Add(tb2) ;
        } 

        //store the created controls on ViewState asociated with the key "lstTitleControls" and "lstAuthorControls"
        // each time you store or access a ViewState you a serialization or deserialization happens which is expensive/heavy
        Session["lstTitleControls"] = lstTbTitles ;
        Session["lstAuthorControls"] = lstTbAuthors ;
    }
    else
    {
        //restore the list of controls from the ViewState using the same key
        lstTbTitles = (List<TextBox>) Session["lstTitleControls"];
        lstTbAuthors = (List<TextBox>) Session["lstAuthorControls"];

        numTextBoxes = lstTbTitles.Count() ;
    }
    //at this moment lstTbTitles and lstTbAuthors has a list of the controls that were just created or recovered from the ViewState
    
    //now add the controls to the page

    for (int i = 1; i <= numTextBoxes; i++)
    {
        pnlBooks.Controls.Add(lstTbTitles[i]);
        pnlBooks.Controls.Add(lstTbAuthors[i]);
        pnlBooks.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateOrLoadTextBoxes(10) ;
}
```

As you have noticed I am calling the CreateOrLoadTextBoxes with a fixed value of 10

Is up to you to chane this code to take the value from the text box and call this as needed

Comment: What do people mean when they talk about using or recreating int he page_init function and can you give an example of using that?

Comment: yes..i am in the process of improving mi initial answer give 10 more minutes

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to keep track of your programmatically or dynamically added controls. It's true that somehow someone has to keep track of them, but it's not you who should be doing so.

Understanding the Page Life-cycle in ASP.NET Web Forms is a must for any ASP.NET developer. Sooner or later you'll run into this sort of problems that would be greatly simplified if you really understood the underlying mechanics of the page.

Each time a request is made to the server, the whole page must be assembled from scratch. You can read (please do) on the web the many steps or stages that make up the Page Life-cycle for an ASP.NET page, but for you to have a rough idea on how this works:

- When the request is made, the .aspx file is parsed and a memory source code created from it. This stage is known as the **Instantiation** stage, and the page's control hierarchy is created at this point.
- After that, page goes through the **Initialization** phase, in which the page's Init event is fired. This is "the place" to add controls dynamically.
- **LoadViewState** phase comes next. At this point, the information of the controls that are part of the page's control hierarchy get their "state" updated to make them return to the state they were before the postback. (This stage doesn't happen on the first time the page is accessed, it's a postback-only stage).
- **LoadPostData** phase is when the data that has been posted to the server (by submitting the form) is loaded into controls. This stage is barely known to beginner ASP.NET developers, because they assume that all "state preservation" that is automatically enforced by ASP.NET engine comes from the magical Viewstate.

NOTE: If you are really serious about this, you can learn A LOT from this guy here: [Understanding ASP.NET View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

What you need to remember from all the above now is that: in order for your dynamically generated controls to "have" their data "glued" together into the control's state after submitting the form by clicking this button `Then I would have a button they click that would save the textbox values into the database.`, you need to add the controls to the page at each round-trip to the server.

The recommended way of doing so is in the `Page_Init`, because it comes before the *LoadViewsate* and *LoadPostData* stages where the control's state is populated.

In your case though, you don't know how many controls to add until the user fills that information on the first form submission. So, you need to find a way to add the controls to the page each time the page loads after the user entered the number of desired controls.

NOTE: You could get away with adding the controls on the `btnBookQty_Click` and have their data preserved correctly, because ASP.NET ***"plays catch-up"*** on the controls, but that's beyond the scope and purpose of this answer.

1. Add a private field to act as a boolean flag and to indicate the number of controls to add.
2. Create a private method that add the controls into the page, taking as argument the number of controls to add.
3. Call that method from within the `Page_Init` event handler, only if the flag dictates that some fields must be added.
4. In `btnBookQty`'s click event handler set the flag to the number provided by the user of the page, and...
5. Call the method to create the dynamically generated controls from within `btnBookQty_Click`.

Here's a template code of what you need. Notice how `HowManyControls` property is stored in the Session to "remember" that value across postbacks:

```
private int HowManyControls {
    get 
    {
        if (Session["HowManyControls"] == null) return 0;
        else return (int)Session["HowManyControls"];
    }
    set
    {
        Session["HowManyControls"] = value;
    }   
}

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.Ispostback && HowManyControls > 0)
    {
        //generate the controls dynamically
        GenerateControls(HowManyControls);  
    }
}


protected void btnBookQty_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get the number of controls to generate dynamically from the user posted values
    HowManyControls = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);

    //generate the controls dynamically
    GenerateControls(HowManyControls);  
}

protected void btnSaveToDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //iterate on the control's collection in pnlBook object.
    for (int i = 1; i <= HowManyControls; i++)
    {
        //save those value to database accessing to the control's properties as you'd regularly do: 
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)pnlBooks.FindControl("TextBoxTitle" + i.ToString());
        TextBox tb2 = (TextBox)pnlBooks.FindControl("TextBoxAuthor" + i.ToString();

        //store these values:
        tb.Text;
        tb2.Text;
    }
}

private void GenerateControls(int count)
{
    if (count == 0) { return; }

    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();
        tb.Text = "Book  " + i.ToString() + " Title";
        tb2.Text = "Book  " + i.ToString() + " Author";
        tb.ID = "TextBoxTitle" + i.ToString();
        tb2.ID = "TextBoxAuthor" + i.ToString();
        pnlBooks.Controls.Add(tb);
        pnlBooks.Controls.Add(tb2);
        pnlBooks.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
    } 
}
```

**EDIT**

I had forgotten that ViewState is not available during Page_Init. I've now modified the answer to use Session instead.