# Values from texbox to dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I don't know how to solve this please help me I have 2 texboxes that you type in 2 numbers like:

```
From: 5

To: 10
```

Button that sends it to the dropdown

Dropdownlist shows

```
5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Comment: Buttonclick
**int x = int.parse(textbox1.text);**
**int y = int.parse(textbox2.text);**

Idont now how to start

Comment: Using javascript or c# ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't show us any code, I wrote my own. Let's call your textboxes as `TextBox1` and `TextBox2`.

On `Click` event of your `Button`, calculate these values as an integer first.

```
int start = Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
int end = Int32.Parse(TextBox2.Text);
```

After that, check your `end` is bigger than `start` and take range with [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with your values;

```
if(end > start)
   IEnumerable<int> list = Enumerable.Range(start, end - start + 1);
```

And finally, bind this list to your dropdownlist like;

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = list;
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

If it is needed, define it's `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` properties as well.

Also look at PostBack concept: [What is a postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251157/what-is-a-postback)

Comment: Probably you should add some explanation when we have PostBack and in the case when we need to Rebind the DropDownList.