# Global Variables lose value in another event

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, events, global-variables

I have following global variables

```
Dim cardNumber As String
Dim txnAmount As String
Dim TerminalID As String
Dim CurrencyCode As String
```

And Values are assigned on a click Event from the result set returned from SP

```
dsCards = Utilities.GetVirtualResultNew(txtCardNumber.Text.Trim)
grdTransactionResultSearch.DataSource = dsCards
grdTransactionResultSearch.DataBind()
cardNumber = IIf(IsDBNull(dsCards.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("pan")), "", dsCards.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("pan"))
txnAmount = IIf(IsDBNull(dsCards.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("TotalAmount")), "", dsCards.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("TotalAmount"))
TerminalID = IIf(IsDBNull(dsCards.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("TerminalID")), "", dsCards.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("TerminalID"))
CurrencyCode = IIf(IsDBNull(dsCards.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("CurrencyCode")), "", dsCards.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("CurrencyCode"))
```

I Debugged the code and I can see the values are assigned to them but when I try to access them in another button click event, They are empty

Here is my button click event where These variables are empty

```
Protected Sub btnAuthorize_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAuthorize.Click
  Utilities.InsertAuthorizedTransactions(cardNumber, txnAmount, TerminalID, CurrencyCode)
  Label1.Visible = True
END Sub
```

Whats the problem with my code?

Comment: When you say "global" where are they actually defined

Comment: Inside the class, before any methods/events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a button is clicked, then a postback is performed ([What is a postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251157/what-is-a-postback)) which in this case will re-initliase your variables.

The preferred option is probably to store your variables in ViewState ([What is ViewState?](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_viewstate.asp)) in your first button click:

```
ViewState("cardNumber") = "foo"
ViewState("txnAmount") = "bar"
'etc.
```

And then access them in your second click.

Note also that you should not use the `IIF` function in VB.NET but you should instead use the `If` *Operator*