# HTML onload script triggered too many times?

Tags: html, asp.net, onload

I created a simple ASP.Net html page. I would like to put a password check, ONLY when the page is initially loaded, I did it with a script and assigned the tag **onload** to the **body**. The problem is, that the password check is triggered every time I press a button. Why does this happens? How can I execute that password check ONLY when you open the page?
Thanks in advance.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="FotoDiClasse.aspx.cs" Inherits="FotoDiClasse" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Choose your sweatshirt</title>
    <!-- password control -->
    <script>
        var password;
        var pass1 = "1234";
        var firstTime = true;

        function checkPassword()
        {
            if (firstTime)
                firstTime = false;
                password = prompt("Enter password to access the site", '');
                if (password != pass1) window.location = "http://www.google.com";
        }      
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="checkPassword()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="CreateButton" runat="server" Text="Create" Width="240px" OnClick="CreateButton_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="SendButton" runat="server" Text="Send" Width="240px" OnClick="SendButton_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This "first time" flag doesn't work

Comment: It should be noted that `password = prompt...` will run whether `firstTime` is true or not, because you're not using curly brackets around your if statements. Just because you indent the code, doesn't mean the code will not run.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because every time  you press a button your page is loaded and `onload()` method is called and hence every time that method is called.

To overcome this problem you need to set some sort of function that check whether your page is loaded first time or not to do this you can use cookie to store that session.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="FotoDiClasse.aspx.cs" Inherits="FotoDiClasse" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Choose your sweatshirt</title>
    <!-- password control -->
    <script>
        var password;
        var pass1 = "1234";
        var firstTime = true;

        function checkPassword()
        {
            if (firstTime)
                firstTime = false;
                password = prompt("Enter password to access the site", '');
                if (password != pass1) window.location = "http://www.google.com";
        }      
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="CreateButton" runat="server" Text="Create" Width="240px" OnClick="CreateButton_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="SendButton" runat="server" Text="Send" Width="240px" OnClick="SendButton_Click" onblur="checkPassword()"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new with Html. Where do you put this in a normal aspx page?

Comment: put inside script tag

Comment: I posted it on the main question

Comment: why don't you check your password onblur of textbox ??

Comment: maybe you're right, I'm doing that. But just in case I needed to do that the first time the page loads, where do I put your code? Thank you very much anyway!! :)

Comment: no problem , happy coding :) in case you need help contact me. i will share tutorial for the cookie that way you can tell your browser that page has been loaded once

Comment: check this tutorial for more detail http://www.devcurry.com/2009/02/how-to-execute-javascript-onload-only.html

Comment: Thank you!! It worked. I thank anyway everyone who helped me!! :)

Comment: No problem anytime i m glad to help you :)   most welcome

Answer (score 0):

It is called [PostBack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251157/what-is-a-postback). Every time a Button is pressed the Page performs a Form Post (PostBack). That means the page is reloaded.

With the snippet below you can call a JavaScript function only when the page is first loaded.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "runScript", "alert('This is not a PostBack');", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I add it?

Comment: `Page_Load` should be present in the `PageName.aspx.cs` file. You add it there.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this one too!! :)

Comment: One thing. What do I write instead of "runScript", the script name, the method or what else?

Comment: That is just a name (Key) you give to that script so you can reference it later if needed. You can change that into something else.

Comment: It din't work :(. I tried but the page keeps loading in a loop. Do I have to copy exactly the content of the code or I have to change something?

Comment: No, you should be able to use it "as is", just replace the `alert` with the actual JavaScript function of course. If you don't have a `.cs` file for the page I can show you how to use in in the aspx itself.