# how to show an Image PopUp after Page Load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

This code is used to create popups on websites. After clicking on the close button once, the popup box goes away but after 3 seconds the fire comes again. I only want this 1 time, not over and over again

```js
            $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#popUp').css('display','block'); }, 3000);
            }); 

        $('.close-popup').click(function(){
            $('#popUp').css('display','none');
        });
```

```html
<div id="popUpmain">
        <form action="">
            <div id="popUp" style="display:none">
                <h1 class="popUp-heading">Sign Up</h1>
                <input type="text" class="pop-up-name" placeholder="Your Name">
                <input type="text" class="pop-up-email" placeholder="Email">
                <input type="text" class="pop-up-number" placeholder="Number">
                <select name="Select Product" id="" class="popup-select">
                    <option value="Select Product active">Select Product</option>
                    <option value="Mattress">Mattress</option>
                    <option value="Select Product active">Comforter</option>
                    <option value="Select Product active">pillow</option>
                </select> 
                <input type="submit" class="popup-btn close-popup">
                <button class="close-btn close-popup">Not Now</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Somehow the page is getting reloaded again. Everytime the page gets reloaded, the `load` event gets triggered and after 3 seconds of page load event, this popup shows in.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your js to this:

basically, you set the timeout function to a variable and then when you close the popup you clear the timeout

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      var popup =   setTimeout(function(){
            $('#popUp').css('display','block'); }, 3000);
        }); 

    $('.close-popup').click(function(){
        $('#popUp').css('display','none');
          clearTimeout(popup);
    });
```

Comment: If you provide a working snippet I'll take a closer look.  Do you get any kind of error in the console?

Comment: no, there is no error in the console. When you close the pop, it goes away but comes back again after 3 seconds that is the problem

Comment: I just updated the snippet  below this.  Looks like it's now working.  Needed to change the scope of the on load

Answer (score 0):

```js
var cnt = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
      cnt++;
      console.log('alert'+ cnt)
      var popup =   setTimeout(function(){
            $('#popUp').css('display','block'); }, 3000);
        

    $('.close-popup').click(function(){
        $('#popUp').css('display','none');
          clearTimeout(popup);
          
    }) });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popUpmain">
        <form action="">
            <div id="popUp" style="display:none">
                <h1 class="popUp-heading">Sign Up</h1>
                <input type="text" class="pop-up-name" placeholder="Your Name">
                <input type="text" class="pop-up-email" placeholder="Email">
                <input type="text" class="pop-up-number" placeholder="Number">
                <select name="Select Product" id="" class="popup-select">
                    <option value="Select Product active">Select Product</option>
                    <option value="Mattress">Mattress</option>
                    <option value="Select Product active">Comforter</option>
                    <option value="Select Product active">pillow</option>
                </select> 
                <input type="submit" class="popup-btn close-popup">
                <button type ='button' class="close-btn close-popup">Not Now</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain why this answer has been posted twice?  I'm not seeing the distinction between the two answers.

Comment: the scope of the onload ready function is different.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying.  It would be helpful if you added some text to explain the answer

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your 'not now' button.

```
<div id="popUpmain">
    <form action="">
        <div id="popUp" style="display:none">
            <h1 class="popUp-heading">Sign Up</h1>
            <input type="text" class="pop-up-name" placeholder="Your Name">
            <input type="text" class="pop-up-email" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="text" class="pop-up-number" placeholder="Number">
            <select name="Select Product" id="" class="popup-select">
                <option value="Select Product active">Select Product</option>
                <option value="Mattress">Mattress</option>
                <option value="Select Product active">Comforter</option>
                <option value="Select Product active">pillow</option>
            </select> 
            <input type="submit" class="popup-btn close-popup">
            <!--<start of problem> -->
            <button class="close-btn close-popup">Not Now</button>
            <!--<end of problem> -->
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

If you change the above:

`<button class="close-btn close-popup">Not Now</button>`

To:

`<button type="button" class="close-btn close-popup">Not Now</button>`

It will prevent the button from submitting the form, avoiding a [post-back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251157/what-is-a-postback#:%7E:text=See%20ASP.NET%20Page%20Life,%2C%20AutoPostBack%20control%20or%20Ajax).), preventing the [document reloading](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/), re-triggering the `$(document).ready(function()` call.

Button types:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp

Comment: Thank you. Can you give me another salve now? When I came back to the home page after visiting other pages of the website, it popped up again. I wanted the web site to show popup only first time loading time. It Will not show even if reloaded at another time.. link this website "https://www.livpuresleep.com/"

Comment: Then you’ll need some form of persistent storage to keep track of their choice to see it. Cookies/Sessions/User account settings may be what you’re looking for.

Comment: can you help me with this PHP query using cookies plz?

Comment: Query will be better if it is JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Your code as made at first follow the right logic!

There is something that you are missing!

This something is that **the button** is **within a form**! And **by default will submit the form**!

Which means **at submit, it will refresh the page**! And so the **page load again**! And `ready` **event** will get executed again! Which will fire again! And it gonna be **an infinit loop if you try the same thing again**! By clicking the button again!

You can prevent that using `e.preventDefault()`:

```js
$('.close-popup').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // <<<< here
    $('#popUp').css('display','none');
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

And here a playground for your code! Even though it's straight forward!

https://jsfiddle.net/mkpzrg3j/1/