# VBScript sends twice without hidden field, but never with it. Need help sending email

Tags: email, asp-classic, vbscript

Ok, so my problem is this. I have a simple vbscript that sends an email when the form is submit. When it is in the code as follows, if sends the email (I receive the email in my inbox) undesirable twice: Once when the page loads, and once on submit:

```
<% Sub sendEmail(mailFrom, mailTo, mailSubject, mailMessage, mailServer, mailUsername, mailPassword)
Set MyMail = CreateObject("cdo.message")
MyMail.From = mailFrom
MyMail.To = mailTo
MyMail.Subject = mailSubject
MyMail.HTMLBody = mailMessage
MyMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
MyMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = mailServer
MyMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = mailUsername
MyMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = mailPassword
MyMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
MyMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
MyMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
MyMail.Send
Set MyMail = nothing
End Sub

Dim mailFrom, mailTo, mailSubject, mailMessage, mailServer, mailUsername, mailPassword

mailFrom = "example"
mailTo = "example"
mailSubject = "Email test"
mailMessage = "<html><body>example</body><html>"
mailServer = "example"
mailUsername = "example"
mailPassword = "example"

Call sendEmail(mailFrom, mailTo, mailSubject, mailMessage, mailServer, mailUsername, mailPassword)%>
```

So I figured I had to do something like this so it only sends once. Add a hidden field to the form under the submit button, and edit the code to this. The only problem is, when I do this, the form appears to submit properly and no errors occur, but I never get the email in my inbox! Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I'm not the best at this stuff, and I'm still learning!:

```
<% if request.form("isSubmitted") = "yes" then
Sub sendEmail(mailFrom, mailTo, mailSubject, mailMessage, mailServer, mailUsername, mailPassword)
Set MyMail = CreateObject("cdo.message")
MyMail.From = mailFrom
MyMail.To = mailTo
MyMail.Subject = mailSubject
MyMail.HTMLBody = mailMessage
MyMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
MyMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = mailServer
MyMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = mailUsername
MyMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = mailPassword
MyMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
MyMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
MyMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
MyMail.Send
Set MyMail = nothing
End Sub

Dim mailFrom, mailTo, mailSubject, mailMessage, mailServer, mailUsername, mailPassword

mailFrom = "example"
mailTo = "example"
mailSubject = "Email test"
mailMessage = "<html><body>example</body><html>"
mailServer = "example"
mailUsername = "example"
mailPassword = "example"

Call sendEmail(mailFrom, mailTo, mailSubject, mailMessage, mailServer, mailUsername, mailPassword)
end if %>
```

Edit #1: This is my hidden field (I've also put the hidden field after the submit button to no avail.)

```
<input type="hidden" name="isSubmitted" id="isSubmitted" value="yes" /> 
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
```

Comment: Have you response.write("ok") within the sub to ensure its executing?

Comment: Pls add your html code so we can see if `isSubmitted` is set properly. Furthermore you could check **Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD")="POST"** instead of using a hiddenField. (see [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128539/asp-check-request-method))

Comment: Alright, I added my submit and hidden field, but let me know if you need more. Also, I'll try that too Alex. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Is your form using `GET` or `POST`, your request.form will only work if the `<form>` uses `POST` - if your form is using `GET`, use `request.querystring("isSubmitted")` instead.

Comment: Alex, I added response.write("ok") before End Sub, and nothing showed up. I'm guessing it's not being executed for some reason?

Comment: Post your whole HTML form - including the `method=''`, `action=''` and `</form>` attributes / tags.

Comment: I've added the updated code. (The function in the vbscript was a recommendation via the comments below.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your form is doing a POST and not a GET ? 
If it's a GET request, you would need request.querystring("isSubmitted") instead

I would also put the check in a function.

```
Function IsSubmit()
    'IsSubmit= (request.form("isSubmitted") = "yes") 'Edited for more generic solution
    IsSubmit = (Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST")
End Function
```

Then you can use __ if IsSubmit() then __ in your code

Comment: No, my form is method="post". I also tried adding the code you recommended but it still doesn't seem to work. (I added what you put right before the if, and changed the if to <% if isSubmit() then %>)

Comment: Hi Kruce, I don't see anything wrong in your code.. I would only put your sendEmail procedure outside of your if statement. I also updated my function to use the more generic solution that Franz Pilgerstorfer suggested.. that's indeed what we normally use in production...

Comment: Oh, that actually worked! The request.servervariables("Request_method") = "Post"! Thank you  Pilgerstorfer Franz and AardVark71!

Comment: I'm going to google it and read up on it myself also, but what exactly is that command doing.. Just to add it to my knowledge base. :p It looks like it's just setting the server variable request_method to post, but why wouldn't it have done that from the method on my form?

Comment: Hi Kruce, it's not setting the server variable but checks the server variables collection to see if the method used to make the request was a POST or not